# How to add extra tab in common browsing widget in drupal commons

Tags: 7

Here i working in Drupal Commons.7.x and i need to add extra tab in that common browsing widget **([Common Browsing Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons_bw))** section in common drupal.How to achieve to add extra tab in common browsing widget in common drupal.Here my need to in that image[image: Common Drupal Browsing Widget]
Here i tried to change using

> **structure => View => Common browsing Widget (Poll,Q&A,Event and etc.,)**

. Need to add extra tab with content.how to achieve it.Kindly guide me.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses Quick Tabs.

You can either goto `admin/structure/quicktabs` and edit the quicktab.

Or you can visit `admin/structure/quicktabs/manage/commons_bw/edit` which is the default quicktab for `browsing widget` directly add any block that you want.

Comment: Hi @Gokul Thank for you response me, but quicktab not added any thing and nothing manage in quicktab..Let me know which section tab wll added?